# Php/MSSQL - Loop Stopping

Tags: php, sql-server, loops

I'm having some trouble with a loop in php.

The loop is something like this:

```
while($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
//Check for a special condition, the id of that item, like if($item['id'] == X)
//for each id, theres a diferente if/else if in which I make another query to get the name
     $query_sql = "SELECT name from another_table where item_id = :id";
     $query_stmt = $handler->prepare($query_sql);
     $query_stmt->bindParam(':id',$item['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $query_stmt->execute();
//fetch the result and put it into a variable
}
```

The problem is that the loop seems to be working only for the first record, so it is probably erroring out somewhere in the middle.
I've also noticed that if I run a query to get the count of all the user items before the loop, then the loop will also fail.

Is there any limit to how many queries you can run in mssql from php?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I should also say that if I don't try to make a query in the middle to get the items name, then the loop will fully work.

EDIT 2:

this is the function i'm using to get the items names:

```
  `function get_item_name($id){
$item_name = "SELECT szName from TABLE_WITH_NAME where wItemID = :id";
$item_name_stmt = $dbg->prepare($item_name);
$item_name_stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$item_name_stmt->execute();
$item_info = $item_name_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$item_name_stmt = null;
return $item_info['szName'];
```

}
`

And a print_r($item) result before running the function:

```
Array ( [dlID] => 3.377699720834E+15 [bStorageType] => 0 [dwStorageID] => 254 [bOwnerType] => 0 [dwOwnerID] => 9910 [bItemID] => 0 [wItemID] => 22105 [bLevel] => 24 [bCount] => 1 [bGLevel] => 0 [dwDuraMax] => 1000000 [dwDuraCur] => 999952 [bRefineCur] => 0 [dEndTime] => 2030-03-09 01:09:00 [bGradeEffect] => 5 [bMagic1] => 11 [bMagic2] => 13 [bMagic3] => 54 [bMagic4] => 0 [bMagic5] => 0 [bMagic6] => 0 [wValue1] => 100 [wValue2] => 43 [wValue3] => 130 [wValue4] => 0 [wValue5] => 0 [wValue6] => 0 [dwTime1] => 0 [dwTime2] => 0 [dwTime3] => 0 [dwTime4] => 0 [dwTime5] => 0 [dwTime6] => 0 [bGem] => 0 [wMoggItemID] => 153 )
```

Trying to get a print_r($item) after running get_item_name($id) function results in no print_r output.

Comment: Does the code here reproduce the problem? You say it's "probably getting stuck somewhere"; have you tried putting some `echo` statements to see where it is getting to? Both things should be part of creating a [mcve], which will help you understand the problem, and help us to help you.

Comment: Inputing the full code would be pretty hard since it involves database connections and etc. I can post some of the code i'm using tho.

Comment: The main thing is that we can't really answer a question about code that is "something like this", "seems to be" doing something, and "probably" has an error. The chances are too high that either we'll spot an unrelated error (as several people already have), or that we'll have no chance of finding the error, because it's in code you haven't shown us. Try to turn on some error logging, dump some data, debug the code, find *where* it's going wrong, then come back and we'll help you understand *why* it's going wrong.

Comment: I've been debugging and found out that when im trying to make a query in the middle of the fetch cycle, the 2nd fetch seems to not get any info from the database. Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `()`?

```
 while($item = stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: nop, that was a mistake when writing the post here, my bad, as i've mentioned, without the 2nd query to get the items name from the database, the loop will work till the end.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a $ on var $stmt:

```
while($item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Comment: Ups, another mistake, but that is not the reason (just an error typing it out in here, same as the mistake above, it was in a hurry ahah) as I've said, the problem seems to come from querying the db for the name.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? I use PDO in a slightly different way, i'm assuming $handler is defined as $handler = new Database(); or something of the sort?

```
while($item = stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $handler->query("SELECT name FROM another_table WHERE item_id = :item_id");
    $handler->bind(':item_id', $item['id']);
    $result = $handler->single();
}
```

Comment: Thing is, i've been using it like this for the whole project, and now it seems to bug out, but it works if I don't query for the name of the item on the database. Which is very weird.

Comment: Can you `print_r($item);` and post the results here? @AndréSoares

Comment: Array ( [dlID] => 3.377699720834E+15 [bStorageType] => 0 [dwStorageID] => 254 [bOwnerType] => 0 [dwOwnerID] => 9910 [bItemID] => 0 [wItemID] => 22105 [bLevel] => 24 [bCount] => 1 [bGLevel] => 0 [dwDuraMax] => 1000000 [dwDuraCur] => 999952 [bRefineCur] => 0 [dEndTime] => 2030-03-09 01:09:00 [bGradeEffect] => 5 [bMagic1] => 11 [bMagic2] => 13 [bMagic3] => 54 [bMagic4] => 0 [bMagic5] => 0 [bMagic6] => 0 [wValue1] => 100 [wValue2] => 43 [wValue3] => 130 [wValue4] => 0 [wValue5] => 0 [wValue6] => 0 ... and it keeps going . THIS IS IF I DO IT BEFORE TRYING TO GET THE NAME VIA THE 2nd query

Comment: @AndréSoares I don't see an id field and your binding the $item['id'] in the SQL. Maybe you meant $item['dIID'] ?

Comment: the id would be wItemID. I edited my original question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is your mistake:
`$query_sql = "SELECT name from another_table where item_id = :item";`
So you want to set the parameter as ":item" BUT:
`$query_stmt->bindParam(':id',$item['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);`
Here, you binded parameter ":id" which is not defined on the query so you should change it to ":item".